# Java Binomial recursion using cache

Tags: java, recursion, caching, binomial-coefficients

I ran into a little problem having to solve the binomial coefficient using a 1d Integer array as a cache. this is my code thus far:

```
static public int computeCached(int n, int k) throws ArithmeticException, IllegalArgumentException {
        if(n < 0 || k < 0 || n < k)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal");

        int cache[] = new int[n + 1];
        return computeCached(n, k, cache);
    }

    
    static int computeCached(int n, int k, int []cache) throws ArithmeticException {
        if(k == 0 || n == k)
            return 1;
        if(cache[n] != 0)
            return cache[n];
        cache[n] = Math.addExact(computeCached(n-1, k, cache), computeCached(n-1,k-1, cache));
        return cache[n];
    }
```

It's supposed to store the calculated value and then add the next value for the next iteration on top.
somehow it doesnt save the right value in the cache and i cant seem to find the problem.
thanks :)

Comment: It might help if you explained a bit how you think this should work, which values you expect to be cached, and which values you actually observe stepping through this. Start with small numbers, e.g. `n= 3`, `k= 1` to get a feeling for how this works.

Comment: The problem is that you have a 2-dimensional problem which subsolutions can't be saved in a simple 1-dimensional array. Your program right now for example saves the solutions for `computeCached(n-1,k,cache)` and `computeCached(n-1,k-1,cache)` in the same position of the array since you only use the value for `n` as index.

Comment: In order to solve this problem you will have to "flatten" pascal's triangle, e.g. by mapping `(n, k)` to the index `((n*(n+1))/2)+k` (just enumerating from left to right, top to bottom, using the sum formular)

Comment: thank you @MDK mapping over ((n*(n+1))/2)+k index did the trick

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is that your mapping is ambiguous. You store all `(n,k)` pairs with different values for `k` in the same array entry. As a solution you will have to calculate a unique index for each combination of `n` and `k`, e.g. `((n*(n+1))/2)+k`, which would "flatten" the triangle using the sum formula. Simpler mappings like `n*k + k` would also work, but required a larger cache than actually needed, with some arry entries never getting used.